# Make strip active or deactivate it in python

Tags: python, nla-editor

I found out that the 'active variable of a strip is read-only.
Is there another way to activate and/or deactivate a strip with python?
Maybe a predefined operator which I can use?

Comment: activate as in selected? or active as in not muted?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with muted, but I don't mean selected. The strip is deselected, but there is still a border around the strip in the nla editor

Comment: The white outline is the strip displaying it's properties in the properties sidebar. deselecting the strip by clicking out side it doesn't appear to make any difference in the vse. Muting a strip stops it showing in the output - as if it isn't there, shortcut is H to hide the strip.

Answer (score 1):

you can select the track and then select the strip inside, which will automatically turn the strip active

```
track.select = True
strip.select = True
```

Referenced from： https://devtalk.blender.org/t/setting-active-nla-strip-via-python/24715

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import bpy
se = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor
se.active_strip = se.sequences['0001.png']
```

There appears to be some lag in the UI that I'm not sure how to work around.